# Do most scientific discoveries commit the conditional probability fallacy?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, conditional-probability, likelihood, posterior

Usually, in an experimental scientific paper where we have observations $X$ taken in laboratory conditions, we either reject some model $\mathcal{M}$ under the basis that $P(X \mid \mathcal{M}) \ll 1$, or we say that some model $\mathcal{M}_1$ is a *better* explanation for $X$ than some other model $\mathcal{M}_0$ because $P(X \mid \mathcal{M}_1) \gg P(X \mid \mathcal{M}_0).$

But isn't this just the [confusion of the inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_of_the_inverse) fallacy? This is the fallacy where you erroneously swap variables in a conditional probability. One simple example of this fallacy is if you sell hand lotion, and you find that most people who buy the hand lotion are women, and you conclude that most women buy hand lotion. The correct conclusion would be that most people who buy hand lotion are women.

When asking the epistemic question of which model is most likely to explain reality (e.g. can light propagation be better explained by Aether theory or Special Relativity), and we do experiments to gain observations $X$, we should care about the posterior distribution, $P(\mathcal{M} \mid X)$, not the likelihood, $P(X \mid \mathcal{M})$, right? Or at least the ratio of that quantity between different models. If the ratio of likelihoods favor one model, that doesn't imply that the model is favored by the ratio of posterior probabilities. We must enter the prior probabilities into the equation. That is,
$$
\frac{P(\mathcal{M_1} \mid X)}{P(\mathcal{M_0} \mid X)} = \frac{P(X \mid \mathcal{M}_1) P(\mathcal{M_1})}{P(X \mid \mathcal{M}_0) P(\mathcal{M_0})} \ne \frac{P(X \mid \mathcal{M}_1)}{P(X \mid \mathcal{M}_0) }.
$$

Only with the above quantity can we confidently say that one model more accurate at describing reality than another, given our experimental observations.

Now, I'm not claiming to have any idea how to evaluate the ratio of prior probabilities between models, or if there's even a possible way to do this. But even if we can't do this, then how can we possibly have any confidence in a particular model for explaining reality, when all we have is the likelihood?

Is there any literature (statistics, science, philosophy, whatever) that discusses this? Is there a good reason to simply ignore the priors of models when comparing them? Am I somehow mistaken in thinking that the posterior of a model is more important than the likelihood when assessing its viability? Is the premise of my question wrong, and scientific discoveries don't only rely on the likelihood for a model? Is there, at least, some loose heuristic for comparing the priors of two model (e.g. Occam's razor, the model with fewer assumptions have greater priors)?

Comment: Yes, there is a huge literature on this. Suggest you start reading up on Bayes Factors.

Comment: This is question is more about epistemology than statistics.  Also, it will be helpful to distinguish between the actual practice of science versus what statisticians say scientists should do.  And that's before getting to the Bayesian vs. Frequentist issue which seems to be the core of your concern.  A lot factors--philosophical, practical, cultural--go into knowledge generation.  It might help to focus your question into some aspect of the contrasting Bayesian and Frequentist modalities.

Comment: @JTH Can you be more specific please? It seems like Bayes factors, on their own, doesn't resolve this dilemma. Bayes factors are defined as the ratio of likelihoods, $P(X \mid \mathcal{M}_1) / P(X \mid \mathcal{M}_0)$. This doesn't solve the problem of not having the ratio of model prior distributions, which is the main problem I'm bringing up. Do you know of literature that addresses this?

Comment: @abstrusiosity I don't see how this is a Bayesian versus Frequentist issue. Whether you calculate $P(X \mid \mathcal{M})$ using Bayesian or Frequentist methods, you're still stuck with not having enough information to specify which model is more likely, given the data. I don't think any frequentist would claim that having $P(A \mid B)$ is enough to say anything about the probability of $B$.

Comment: @Bridgeburners A BF is not a ratio of likelihoods, it is a ratio of evidences (in Bayesian terms). The model parameters are integrated out of the likelihoods to leave the evidence, Pr(X), under M1 and M0. Since Pr(M1) and Pr(M0) differ from person to person, Bayesians tend to use the Bayes Factor instead of the posterior probability of M1 vs. M0.

Comment: @JTH Okay, so that is my mistake in nomenclature. But it's still the case that model evidence is the probability of data given model, not vice versa. It's just also doesn't include model parameters in the conditional bracket, because that was integrated out. But it doesn't solve the dilemma I'm talking about. You brushed on the problem a bit by saying "[model priors] differ from person to person", but even if it does, how can we pick one model over another only knowing the ratio of $P(X \mid M)$? Isn't that the confusion of inverse fallacy?